# linux pppoe vs dhcp

Tags: dhcp, static, pppoe

Ноутбук с Ubuntu 14.*
Домой провел инет -подключение по PPPoe - для подключения использую pppoeconf.
На работе инет через DHCP - по кабелю подключиться не удалось.
Пробовал  poff /прописать статику через networkManager/ ifconfig - не помогло, думал в автоматическом подключении дело , но нет - постоянно висит значек c сетью в Network Manager.

в ifconfig следующее (даже без кабла):

```
    enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:cd:a7:1f  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:20 Память:f2500000-f2520000 

enp0s25:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:cd:a7:1f  
          inet addr:169.254.9.95  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:20 Память:f2500000-f2520000
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s25
iface enp0s25 inet dhcp

#мной закоментировано
#auto dsl-provider
#iface dsl-provider inet ppp
#pre-up /bin/ip link set enp0s25 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
#provider dsl-provider
```

Как отключить pppoe и прописать статику/использовать dhcp ?
PS:  в network manager при вводе маски 255.255.255.0 стала автоматически меняться на 24 )

Comment: На работе кем работаете? Админом или клерком? Админ вроде сам должен всё знать, а клерк должен спросить своего админа как что можно подключить. Может dchp нет на работе(встречаются ещё  админы, которые не умеют наладить dhcp. Тогда нужна статика. Тут без админа совсем никак. Он должен выдать адреса, маски. Как прописать всё это в interfaces можно почитать здесь  https://wiki.debian.org/ru/NetworkConfiguration Убунта вроде не сильно отличается от дебияна в этом аспекте.

Comment: А не пробовали всё (dsl, dhcp, статику) настроить через NetworkManager и переключаться с помощью него?

Comment: Sergey - ни тем ,ни этим ) эт понятно ..так как при через interface отпределить статика у нас или pppoe ?  и как переключиться (туда и обратно не трогая sudo /etc/network/integraces  restart) ?

Roman - NM  смотрит на эти два интерефейса ,порожденные pppoeconf и показывает кабло (пока wifi не находит). Позже отпишусь.. но pppoe  не удалось настроить через NM (во всяком случаи при монтажнике)

Comment: Roman- NM -  не видит ppp0 =(

Comment: NM и не должен видеть ppp-интерфейс, он должен его создавать. Для этого нужно в NM создать новое DSL подключение, вбить настройки и надеяться, что заработает. Естественно, перед этим отменить всё, что было сконфигурировано вручную.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тему закрываю, о проблеме в двух словах, если кто-то/что-то прописало в /etc/network/interfaces о работе с NetworkManager можно забыть. Всем спасибо.